# Keyboard mapping for chorded keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, driver, keymapping

I want to create a new keymapping on macosx, so I can create advanced multi-key commands.
Basically, I want to create a a keymapping for transforming a normal keyboard into a chorded keyboard, optimized for writing code in c-like languages.

What I am wondering, is it possible to create that general keymaps, or is it possible to create a layer in the OS, intercepting the keyboard input at a low level and implementing the transform there.

If not, does anybody know where I can find sourcecode for a driver for a general HID-keyboard, that I can use as a base for a keyboard driver doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is where you want to start:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html

I'm interested in trying out the same thing actually, I really dislike most of the chorded keyboards I see and would prefer to prototype w/o building the h/w.